# Autohotkey script running program with command line arguments

Tags: command-line-arguments, autohotkey

I am using autohotkey to automate some manual process. 
I have to run a java command line program(.java) that accepts couple of command line arguments.

I want to run this java program from autohotkey after executing some pre-defined tasks in the automation.

How would I do this?

Comment: Vote to close as [crossposting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11014479/312172) just 3h later.

Answer (score 7):

I think that this is what you are looking for. In this example, I over-ride the company default search engine inside IE.

```
#i::Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://www.google.com
```

Basically, put the run pointer between  double quotes and the arguments after that. Let me know how you resolve it.