# how to run java .class file from an autohotkey script?

Tags: java, autohotkey

How to run java .class file from a script providing some command line parameters? The script is built using autohotkey framework. Can we trigger the execution of .class files from a script? Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: You cannot run a class file directly. You run the executable java or javaw, usually with a jar file as the argument. So if autohotkey can run an executable, it can run Java.

Comment: [Crossposting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011527/autohotkey-script-running-program-with-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with autohotkey, but if your command line is something like

```
java -cp <yourclasspath> <yourclassname> <yourarguments>
```

you are good to go, I guess.

**ADDITION:**

It seems to me that the [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) directive allows you to do that. Assuming to have your `MyClass.class` file (with MyClass in the default package) in `C:\mypath`, I expect you have to issue something like

```
Run,java -cp . MyClass,C:\mypath
```

I am not able to verify the above line, since I do not have a Windows installation at hand.